# How to have an XML file in my App?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need an XML file in my app, so I added it to `Files` part of `AppResources.resx` and it appeared in Resources folder with its name `myFile.xml`

```
var myFile = MyApp.Resources.AppResources.myFile;
```

this just returns a string value, and this is not what I want.

`XmlSerializer` needs a stream to an existing file to deserialize it, so I don't know what to do with this string?

How can I have an xml variable of that file? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.stringreader%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
        var myFile = MyApp.Resources.AppResources.myFile;

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(myFile);
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        var classInstance = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can just use MapPath to resolve the file-path and use that directly to open a appender and serialize your object (in this case I am using a sample class Foo with a single property Name) there. Let me know if I am wrong in understanding your requirement.

```
using(var stream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Append))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Foo));

                var @object = new Foo
                    {
                        Name = "Bar"
                    }; 

                serializer.Serialize(stream, @object);
            }
```

This is gonna append something along the line of

```
<Foo>
  <Name>Bar</Name>
</Foo>
```